# Dynamically generate spark Sql selectExpr statement for coalesce

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on a project where I need to dynamically provide multiple column names from different sources to coalsace.

**e1.csv**

```
id,code,type
1,,A
2,,
3,123,I
```

**e2.csv**

```
id,code,type
1,456,A
2,789,A1
3,,C
```

### code

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("C:\\Users\\System2\\Videos\\folder\\e1.csv");

Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("C:\\Users\\System2\\Videos\\folder\\e2.csv");



Dataset<Row> newDS = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b")).where("a.id== b.id").selectExpr("coalesce(a.id, b.id) AS `id`;coalesce(a.code, b.code) AS `code`");
```

### Error code I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input ';' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 38)
```

### What I have tried

tried with  `\n`, `,` , `;` but none are working

```
Dataset<Row> newDS = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b")).where("a.id== b.id").selectExpr("coalesce(a.id, b.id) AS `id \n coalesce(a.code, b.code) AS `code`");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Syntax is wrong . Your code will be similar like this :

```
Dataset<Row> newDS = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b")).where("a.id== b.id").selectExpr("coalesce(a.id, b.id) AS `id`","coalesce(a.code, b.code) AS `code`");
```